# Is there a way in Excel to combine the contents of multiple cells and still leave line breaks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

Consider:

```
+---+----------------------+           
|   |        A             |
+---+----------------------+    
| 1 | Instructions to foo  | 
+---+----------------------+   
| 2 | 1.) Foo              |
+---+----------------------+   
| 3 | 2.) Foo again        |
+---+----------------------+   
| 4 | 3.) if foo, then bar |
+---|----------------------+
```

and I WANT

```
+---+----------------------+           
|   |        A             |
+---+----------------------+    
|   |Instructions to foo   | 
| 1 | 1.) Foo              |
|   | 2.) Foo again        |
|   | 3.) if foo, then bar |
+---|----------------------+
```

I know that `CONCATENATE(A2+" "+A3+" "+A4)` or the ampersand `A2&" "&A3" "&A4` will yield `1.) Foo  2.) Foo again  3.) if foo, then bar` but I can't find a way to merge contents WITH line breaks intact.

I'm hoping there's some sort of formula equivalent of `Alt-Enter` so I could do this:
`A2&<Alt-Enter>&A3&<Alt-Enter>&A4` to achieve the deisred results.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Linefeed character:

```
=B1 & CHAR(10) & B2
```

You need to have Wrap Text enabled on the cells for it to display correctly.

Comment: Awesome. Had no idea that existed...thanks for the tip!